# Secure data PUT from IoT devices to DRF backend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ip, iot

I have not been able to find any helpful material on this subject. I am looking for a primer on how to restrict certain endpoints in DRF to accept data from only certain 'whitelisted' IP address.

I am aware of adding the IPs to 'REMOTE_ADDR' settings but that doesn't fully solve my problem. Users will have IoT devices with static IPs. Data streaming from these devices need to be added to the db in a secure manner with the User/tenant specific information along with it.

I am thinking IP restriction might be the best way of going about it. Please let me know if there are other better ways.

Frameworks used:
DRF
django_tenants
Postgresql

Comment: If you have the list of the IPs allowed for each user, you could add a permission class to the affected views that matches the user to the whitelisted IPs and refusees requests with umatched IPs

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any documentation in mind that I can refer to?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/